# Java and stacks: correct implementation?

Tags: java, stack

I created this very simple stack concept's implementation.
Could you tell me if it is correct and clean? Do you see any bad coding habits?

```
public class MyStack
{
    private static final int MAXELEMENTS = 10;
    private int[] elements;
    private int numElements;

    public MyStack()
    {
        numElements = 0;
        elements = new int[MAXELEMENTS];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (numElements == 0);
    }

    public boolean isFull()
    {
        return (numElements == MAXELEMENTS);
    }

    public void push(int e)
    {
        if (!isFull())
            elements[numElements++] = e;
    }

    public int top()
    {
        if (!isEmpty())
            return elements[numElements - 1];
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public void pop()
    {
        if (!isEmpty())
            numElements--;
    }
}
```

You can use it with the following code:

```
class MyStackTestDrive
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyStack s1 = new MyStack();
        MyStack s2 = new MyStack();
        s1.push(2);
        s2.push(4);
        System.out.println(s1.top());
        System.out.println(s2.top());
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get better answers asking this in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would say look at java.lang.Stack for a good implementation

Comment: @Chris Where can I look for it?

Comment: look in JDK source. Type Ctrl+Shift+T and say "Stack" and select the one from JDK. If you don't have source attached, download it

Comment: The source can also be seen at http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Stack.java.html. The source code for the core java libraries are installed with the JDK, they're in a file called src.zip in your JAVAHOME directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things I would do, some of them just a matter of preference :

- Rename "numElements" to "head" to better reflect its function.
- Add a constructor where the max size of the stack can be specified.
- The pop method should return the top element of the stack and remove it. That is the standard semantic.
- top and pop should throw an exception when called on an empty stack. This is to prevent errors where an empty stack is being operated without checking it first.

Answer (score 2):

My comments are:

1. This will be a stack for `int` only. You should make it generic
2. This is a stack for only 10 elements. Not of much use
3. `numElements` is a bad name for top of the stack variable
4. `top` should `throw` and exception for empty stack (traditionally)
5. `pop` should return the top of the stack. Right now it is `void`

Answer (score 1):

You should try to make your stack generic (if you want to allow any other type to be added to) also, you should try to make it grow automatically, by using a check within your push method and if it's full then you reallocate space for it (creating another array, maybe of twice previous space and realocating each by one). Any way you're using arrays instead of a linked list, for example, and that IMHO is a god idea.